Pop up notifications are missing
The pop up messages/notifications do not display when I complete actions. I am using 4.2, previously when I saved my project, at the bottom centre of the screen, a pop up message would say 'project saved' or when I merged vertices by distance, a pop up message would say '5 vertices merged'.
But at the moment none of these pop up anymore and I don't know how to get the back. I might have hit a short cut and now I don't know how to reverse it.
Can anybody help me with this?

Make sure you have enabled Show Status Bar in the Window menu:

Apart from disabling it in the menu, you could have accidentally clicked and dragged between lowest editor window and the status bar, dragging it down will hide it.
And by clicking and dragging upwards from the bottom you can get it back, alternatively to enabling it in the menu.
